# Compiler portable PDB(Program Database)?

Tags: c++

Is there a standardized program database? I looked into the MAP file that the linker generates but it does not contain nearly enough information that I need. And I rather not use PDB because it is not officially documented and it is only for visual studio.

Comment: Please, edit your question to be more legible. It helps a lot to get more/better answers to make the question _easy to understand_. In any case, I don't code C++, so I'm not of much help. But probably every compiler stores more or less information about various topics. I didn't understand what You want to do with that info, that can't be done already. But it may be me too.

Comment: What do you need the PDB for?  Why do you care if it's portable?

Comment: I made a stack walker but it is limited to debug mode because in release the stack frame can be omitted. With a program database I can look up how every function affects the stack without the stack frame and frame pointer.

Comment: If this is an important scenario, don't omit the frame pointer so you can get a stack in release mode.  FPO isn't as much of a perf gain as it was before - Windows Vista and Windows 7 aren't compiled with FPO - http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2007/03/12/fpo.aspx.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D. How do you compile without FPO?

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. You have to specify /Oy- otherwise it will still sometimes do the FPO. Although it would still be nice to have the debug information so I can do even more then just have the function stack frame size.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you have a look at the [google-crashpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/) project. They seem to have common a [symbol file format](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/wiki/SymbolFiles) and corresponding tool to generate these files from platform specific symbol file formats.

AFAIK, Firefox project uses this library on the client side for crash reporting and on the server side, they employ this symbol file format for stack traces for the crash reports.